# esp8266 - how to write to code segment on the spi?

Tags: esp8266, esp32

on `esp8266`, I dumped the first few hundreds of bytes of onboard `spi`.
It seems to hold the code segment:

```
.y......b.1..*3...F..L..b.1..0".............? !.........] M.=.!......".B..I.2.09 => 7040                                                                                                      
...Y!-.E....!.... ...!..E...!..!..!..!.....P.........9QIaYqi.y.1k.2...3B..I.2. 9 => 7120                                                                                                      
..EY!E......|.....@........?.....@.... ................. ..?....load partition t => 7200                                                                                                      
able error!.boot....26.7MHz.40MHz...20MHz...80MHz...QOUT....DIO.DOUT....2MB.1MB. => 7280                                                                                                      
4MB.16MB....8MB.SPI Speed      : %s.SPI Mode       : %s.SPI Flash Size : %s.fail => 7360                                                                                                      
ed to load bootloader header!...v3.4-dev-347-g1be2289f..ESP-IDF %s 2nd stage boo => 7440                                                                                                      
tloader.compile time 14:13:47......@...@...@...@...@...@...@...@...@...@ is not  => 7520                                                                                                      
bootable....Factory app partition%s.Factory test app partition%s....OTA app part => 7600                                                                                                      
ition slot %d%s.Loaded app from partition at offset 0x%x....RF data.test app.... => 7680
```

My idea is to allow reprogramming the esp over WiFi.
I want to write into these code-segments and restart.

But, i get a `checksum` error, which is probably added by the sdk.
How can i disable the checksum?

```
Restarting now.

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)

load 0x40100000, len 7208, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x63
load 0x3ffe8408, len 24, room 0 
tail 8
chksum 0xea
load 0x3ffe8420, len 3536, room 0 
tail 0
chksum 0xff
csum 0xff
csum err
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7)
```

Comment: you mean the external flash memory? SPI is a communication protocol.

Comment: the SDK supports OTA upload. you don't have to hack it

Comment: where can find the documentation for an OTA example?

Comment: SDK or Arduino?

Comment: esp-idf/examples/system/ota